# Android : save some variabiles

Tags: android

I want to save some variabiles when the activity go to pause. I have think to use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState but the onRestoreInstanceState not always is call. How can I do ? I must use the SharedPreferences or there is another method ?

Thank you

Comment: You can create same name variable in each Method........

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState() call after onStart() (not after onPause())

Answer (score 0):

you can use the SharedPreferences to save when your activity is in the onPause() state and restore when is in the onResume() state. If SharedPreferences does not suit your purpose you can always save the variables in a file, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are different methods are used to the save the variable when the activity onpause like use the static,sharedpreferences,intent.